# Build Strapi on Azure Windows WebApp returns 500 error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-devops-rest-api, strapi, azure-deployment

I deployed Strapi API on Azure (Windows IIS).

I do not get any error under deployment. I used this way to deploy https://github.com/youkou2/Strapi-On-Azure-WebApp

When I start the site https://oskogencms.azurewebsites.net I get 500 error (see image)

[image]

Result of the deployment is here

[image]

Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: How is the progress on this issue? Do you need further help?

Comment: Hi Jason, I am really sorry. I had no possibility to test it. I will do it as soon as I can. Thank you for your help! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Hi Jason, Your post did not help me as expected. As you see files from KUDUS are there. It is not a problem to deploy these files to production app service. My question was why all the files there, but I do not get any start page? And this 500 code error. Why do I get it? Do you have the same file structure in your prod environment? What is in your web.config?

Comment: I suggest you follow my steps step by step, you can definitely try to succeed. My sample URL is provided in the comment, you can also test that your 500 Error does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

In local, u need run `D:\path\Strapi-On-Azure-WebApp-master> npm run-script build` to build your admin page.

Then you need to compress the build folder into a build.zip file, and drag it into kudu.  Open F12 to check the file upload progress.

[image]

When the transfer is successful, you can click the `/admin` link in the website like local.

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

Based on your screenshot and description, I created a web app. Using the Windows platform node 12 LTS.

[image]

Step 1. First, I first create a webapp on the portal, and then use FTP to upload the downloaded source code, unzip it and upload it directly to the wwwroot path.

[image]

Step 2. Install the dependencies in `npm i` in the locally decompressed project, and then run the debug locally by`npm start`. After confirming that there is no problem, compress the `node_modules` folder into a zip file with the file name `node_modules.zip`.

[image]

Step 3. Open kudu on the portal, and then F12, set `window.localStorage ['maxViewItems'] = 3000`, the actual maximum number of files in our project is 1190. Go to the `D:\home\site\wwwroot>` folder, then drag the `node_modules.zip` file directly into the directory, azure will automatically decompress and save the file to the directory, you need to wait for a while, it is recommended to open node_modules Folder, to see the change in the number of files, or in F12 Network to see the change in traffic, waiting for the transmission to complete. You must wait transfer success, it will cost your a long time.

Step 3. After all are completed, directly start the command `D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm start` will report an error, first need to`D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm install sqlite3 --save` It will also report an error but it does not matter. In the second step, execute `D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm i`, because the dependent packages that may not be successfully installed need to be re-detected and installed. Finally, execute `D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm start` to start successfully.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks a lot for so extended answer. I wil go to the office today and check it out. :)

Comment: @podeig Did you follow my steps step by step? I provided the sample code. I followed the steps to try to deploy. After the deployment, there was no error you said, so I am sure that your problem should be in the deployment.

This is the URL after my successful deployment. I suggest you test it, and following my steps should solve your problem.

https://panshubeinodeappwin.azurewebsites.net/

https://panshubeinodeappwin.azurewebsites.net/admin/auth/register